React Keycloak cant login to a client credentials getting 401
The reason why i want to use client authentication is to use the token to add users/group/roles and and most of the api functions.
I have been trying to use the ReactKeyClaokProvider from keycloak module in react to login into a client with client authentication, thus needing a client secret. I am currently using .env to store all the client info including url, realm, and clientId, with this i managed to log in without client authentication but when I add client_secret in the keycloak.d.ts file and turn on the client authentication setting I get a 401 and can't log in.
I cant seem to figure it out, I only manage to log in with out the secret and client authentication setting turn off.
May I know how should I set it up?
I try adding a clientSecret even a credentials: {secret: string} to the keycloak.d.ts file to log in and it didn't work. still get a 401, even when I updated my .env file and the keycloak file that import keycloak.js.

I have solve it the issues was i wasn't parsing the relevant data to the token in the keycloak UI, under the default realm role. which didn't give us all any of the user information and their realm perms.
